# Android Studio AdapterView crashes

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm new in Java and Android Studio.
I'm trying to create a list in my application.
The list should contain a picture and a name in each row.

I followed a tutorial that I've found, the program compiles with no errors, but when I run it - it crashes.

Here is the code:

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    int[] book_poster_resource = { R.mipmap.book_1,
    R.mipmap.book_2};
    String[] book_titles;
    BookAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        book_titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.book_titles);
        int i = 0;
        adapter = new BookAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        for(String titles: book_titles)
        {
            BookDataProvider dataProvider = new BookDataProvider(book_poster_resource[i],
                    titles);
            adapter.add(dataProvider);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.amit.adapterview.MainActivity"
    android:background="#000000">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

BookDataProvider.java:

```
package com.example.amit.adapterview;

public class BookDataProvider {
    private int book_poster_resource;
    private String book_title;

    public BookDataProvider(int book_poster_resource, String book_title) {
        this.book_poster_resource = book_poster_resource;
        this.book_title = book_title;
    }

    public int getBook_poster_resource() {
        return book_poster_resource;
    }

    public void setBook_poster_resource(int book_poster_resource) {
        this.book_poster_resource = book_poster_resource;
    }

    public String getBook_title() {
        return book_title;
    }

    public void setBook_title(String book_title) {
        this.book_title = book_title;
    }
}
```

BookAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.amit.adapterview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Amit on 23/11/2015.
 */
public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    List list = new ArrayList();

    public BookAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    static class DataHandler
    {
        ImageView poster;
        TextView title;
    }


    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;
        row = convertView;
        DataHandler handler;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
            handler = new DataHandler();
            handler.poster = (ImageView)
            row.findViewById(R.id.book_poster);
            handler.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
            row.setTag(handler);
        }
        else
        {
            handler = (DataHandler) row.getTag();
        }
        BookDataProvider dataProvider;
        dataProvider = (BookDataProvider) this.getItem(position);
 handler.poster.setImageResource(dataProvider.getBook_poster_resource());
        handler.title.setText(dataProvider.getBook_title());

        return row;
    }
}
```

row_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#000000">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/book_poster"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/book_1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/book_title"
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/book_poster"
            android:text="Book Name"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <!-- separate line-->
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_below="@+id/book_poster"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Anyone knows why it crashes please?

One of the errors I get is:

```
at com.example.amit.adapterview.BookAdapter.getView(BookAdapter.java:56)
```

When I click on "BookAdapter.java:56" I redirected to the line:

```
row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
```

(in BookAdapter.java)

Thanks for helping!

===================

EDIT:

While debugging I noticed that the crashes happen somewhere in class called "Choreographer.java". There is a function called "doFrame":

```
void doFrame(long frameTimeNanos, int frame) {
        final long startNanos;
        synchronized (mLock) {
            if (!mFrameScheduled) {
                return; // no work to do
            }

            if (DEBUG_JANK && mDebugPrintNextFrameTimeDelta) {
                mDebugPrintNextFrameTimeDelta = false;
                Log.d(TAG, "Frame time delta: "
                        + ((frameTimeNanos - mLastFrameTimeNanos) * 0.000001f) + " ms");
            }

            long intendedFrameTimeNanos = frameTimeNanos;
            startNanos = System.nanoTime();
            final long jitterNanos = startNanos - frameTimeNanos;
            if (jitterNanos >= mFrameIntervalNanos) {
                final long skippedFrames = jitterNanos / mFrameIntervalNanos;
                if (skippedFrames >= SKIPPED_FRAME_WARNING_LIMIT) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Skipped " + skippedFrames + " frames!  "
                            + "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.");
                }
                final long lastFrameOffset = jitterNanos % mFrameIntervalNanos;
                if (DEBUG_JANK) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Missed vsync by " + (jitterNanos * 0.000001f) + " ms "
                            + "which is more than the frame interval of "
                            + (mFrameIntervalNanos * 0.000001f) + " ms!  "
                            + "Skipping " + skippedFrames + " frames and setting frame "
                            + "time to " + (lastFrameOffset * 0.000001f) + " ms in the past.");
                }
                frameTimeNanos = startNanos - lastFrameOffset;
            }

            if (frameTimeNanos < mLastFrameTimeNanos) {
                if (DEBUG_JANK) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Frame time appears to be going backwards.  May be due to a "
                            + "previously skipped frame.  Waiting for next vsync.");
                }
                scheduleVsyncLocked();
                return;
            }

            mFrameInfo.setVsync(intendedFrameTimeNanos, frameTimeNanos);
            mFrameScheduled = false;
            mLastFrameTimeNanos = frameTimeNanos;
        }

        try {
            Trace.traceBegin(Trace.TRACE_TAG_VIEW, "Choreographer#doFrame");

            mFrameInfo.markInputHandlingStart();
            doCallbacks(Choreographer.CALLBACK_INPUT, frameTimeNanos);  // AFTER THIS LINE

            mFrameInfo.markAnimationsStart();
            doCallbacks(Choreographer.CALLBACK_ANIMATION, frameTimeNanos);

            mFrameInfo.markPerformTraversalsStart();
            doCallbacks(Choreographer.CALLBACK_TRAVERSAL, frameTimeNanos);

            doCallbacks(Choreographer.CALLBACK_COMMIT, frameTimeNanos);
        } finally {
            Trace.traceEnd(Trace.TRACE_TAG_VIEW);
        }

        if (DEBUG_FRAMES) {
            final long endNanos = System.nanoTime();
            Log.d(TAG, "Frame " + frame + ": Finished, took "
                    + (endNanos - startNanos) * 0.000001f + " ms, latency "
                    + (startNanos - frameTimeNanos) * 0.000001f + " ms.");
        }
    }
```

In the "try" block, I marked the line that after running it, the program crashes.
I don't know if it's ignorable, but I have a lot of "Cannot resolve" errors in this class. Like "Cannot resolve method 'traceBegin(?,java.lang.String)'" (two lines above the line I marked). And so more...

Small part of the errors list:

```
11-24 22:31:42.905 16091-16091/com.example.amit.adapterview E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 200815888-byte allocation.
11-24 22:31:42.935 16091-16091/com.example.amit.adapterview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 22:31:42.935 16091-16091/com.example.amit.adapterview E/AndroidRuntime: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
11-24 22:31:42.935 16091-16091/com.example.amit.adapterview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
11-24 22:31:42.935 16091-16091/com.example.amit.adapterview E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-24 22:31:42.935 16091-16091/com.example.amit.adapterview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
11-24 22:31:42.935 16091-16091/com.example.amit.adapterview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
11-24 22:31:42.935 16091-16091/com.example.amit.adapterview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
11-24 22:31:42.935 16091-16091/com.example.amit.adapterview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
11-24 22:31:42.935 16091-16091/com.example.amit.adapterview E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
11-24 22:31:42.935 16091-16091/com.example.amit.adapterview E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.amit.adapterview.BookAdapter.getView(BookAdapter.java:55)
```

Comment: row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null, true); try and share any errors or results.

Comment: Again, when the application starts, only white screen is opened and the a message that the application stopped. Watch my edit above.

Comment: You ran out of memory trying to allocate 200MB to create an ImageView.  Why are you allocating 200MB? Is the source of the ImageView that large?

Comment: Both images are less than 2MB. I don't know why it's trying to allocate 200MB. Anyway, this suppose to be the base program. I intend to setup the list so it will get the images from SQL server. But now it's just for checking...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, there was a problem with the images.
Following dsh response, I tried to use other images and now it's running.

Thanks!